# Jekyll YAML data file variables grouping

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to group some variables in YAML but I can't display them in HTML.

I need to group the variables in a certain way. So, I have this in a data file (`facultate.yml`):

```
an1:
  - sem1:
    - materie: Example 1
      pdf: nimic
    - materie: Example 2
      pdf: nimic
  - sem2:
    - materie: Example 3
      pdf: nimic

an2:
  - sem1:
    - materie: Example 4
      pdf: nimic
  - sem2:
    - materie: Example 5
      pdf: nimic
```

And I have this in the HTML file:

```
---
layout: compress
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
PDF-uri facultate
<br />
<br />{% assign nrani = 0 %}{% for an in site.data.facultate %}{% assign nrani = nrani | plus: 1 %}An: {{ nrani }} {% assign nrsem = 0 %}Sem:{% for sem in an %}{% assign nrsem = nrsem | plus: 1 %}{{ nrsem }} {% endfor %}<br />{% endfor %}
<br />{% for item in sem %}{{ item.materie }}{% endfor %}
</html>
```

And I can't display the contents of `materie` or `pdf` variables from `facultate.yml`. I tried different approaches like nesting `{% for item in sem %}` inside the other `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up you yml like this:

```
- an:
  - sem:
    - materie: Example 1
      pdf: nimic
    - materie: Example 2
      pdf: nimic
  - sem:
    - materie: Example 3
      pdf: nimic

- an:
  - sem:
    - materie: Example 4
      pdf: nimic
  - sem:
    - materie: Example 5
      pdf: nimic
```